# CRC Calculation with x^2+x divisor

Tags: binary

I'm studying in French, so I'll try to translate the terms as best as I can, so sorry if it may be unclear.

I have to find the coded message (CRC) with this 10 bits message : 0011111111 and x^2 + x as the polynomial divisor.

I don't have much knowledge in binary and CRC yet, but I still know how to calculate one, but this one is a bit more tricky for me since the polynomial divisor is not an usual one.

There are a lot of examples with divisors such as x^5 + x^4 + 1, but I have yet to find an example with something that resemble this one (x^2 + x).

Here's what I did, but I'm pretty sure that it isn't right at all

```
001111111100 |  110
  110
  00111
    110 
    00111
      110
      00110
        110
        0000
```

Do you guys have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :
[Computation of CRC with 110 on 0011111111](https://ghsi.de/CRC/indexDetails.php?Polynom=110&Message=FF), and see that the result is 2, with a good explanation step by step.

Comment: While your link confirm that it's possible to calculate a CRC with 110, I don't understand the explanation. What is "Next hex digit [0]:
   Shift in of [0] results in 00
   Shift in of [0] results in 00
   Shift in of [0] results in 00
   Shift in of [0] results in 00" supposed to mean?